# How are ABAP data clusters stored in the database?

Tags: database, abap

It's possible to store data clusters inside the database using `import` and `export` statements, together with a dictionary table which adheres to a template (at least has the fields `MANDT, RELID, SRTFD, SRTF2, CLUSTR, CLUSTD`).

Here's two example statements which store/retrieve an entire internal table `ta_test` as a data cluster with name `testtab` and id `TEST` in the database, using dictionary table `ztest`, and area `AA`

```
export testtab = ta_test to database ztest(AA) id 'TEST'.
import testtab = ta_test from database ztest(AA) id 'TEST'.
```

Looking at the contents of the `ztest` table, I see the following records (first 4 fields are the primary key):

```
MANDT   200
RELID   AA
SRTFD   TEST
SRTF2   0 (auto-incremented for each record)
CLUSTR  integer value with a maximum of 2.886
CLUSTD  a 128 character hexadecimal string
```

I've also noticed that the amount of data stored this way is a lot less than the data which was inside the internal table (for instance, 1.000.000 unique records in the internal table result in only 1.703 records inside the `ztest` table). Setting `compression off` on the `export` statement does increase the amount of records, but it's still a lot less.

My questions: does anyone know how this works exactly? Is the actual data stored elsewhere and does `ztest` contain pointers to it? Compression? Encryption? Is the actual data accessible directly from the database (skipping the ABAP layer)?

Comment: What would you need direct access for?

Comment: I don't need access, I'm just curious how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal format of data clusters is not documented (at least not in an official documentation). From my experience, it does contain the entire data and not just pointers: Transporting the table entries to a different system -- as you do frequently when transporting ALV list layouts -- is sufficient to move the contents over. Moreover, the binary blob does not seem to contain much information about the data structure - if you change the source/target structure in an incompatible way, you risk losing data. Direct access from the database layer is not possible (this is actually stated in numerous places all over the documentation). It might be possible to reverse-engineer the marshalling/unmarshalling algorithm, but why bother when you've got the language statement to access the contents at hand?

Comment: "why bother?" - for mass processing. If you process large numbers of items (10k+), it becomes extremely slow to use the language statements in a loop. Maybe there is no way, but it's certainly worth trying to find a mass-processing options.

Answer (score 0):

To complete vwegert answer, here are the only documentations around what SAP calls "data clusters" (but nothing about the compression algorithm itself):

- [Data Cluster](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abendata_cluster.htm)
- [EXPORT parameter_list TO medium [COMPRESSION {ON|OFF}].](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapexport_data_cluster.htm)

  - Excerpts ABAP 7.58: "*For optimization reasons, the binary content of the data cluster can depend on the way it is stored. When reconstructed, a data cluster stored in multiple parts is not necessarily the same as a data cluster stored as a single cluster.*"
  - "**This means that a data cluster can usually only be imported using an IMPORT statement that matches the storage method."**
  - "*Especially, a data cluster stored in a structure for export/import tables in multiple rows cannot necessarily be concatenated into a byte string that can be imported with FROM DATA BUFFER. Even data clusters stored in multiple rows can differ between storage methods. That means a data cluster stored with INTERNAL TABLE can differ from a data cluster for the same data in export/import tables, especially, if they were stored in different releases or for different code pages.*"
- If the type of medium concerns the database, the storage table is called an [Export/Import Table](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexport_data_cluster_indx.htm).
- In case the ABAP system has a different version from the ABAP version when data was stored, `IMPORT` may not be sufficient, [`CL_ABAP_EXPIMP_UTILITIES`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_expimp.htm) may need to be used.