# Issues decoding `CLUSTD` field from BALDAT in SAP Oracle database

Tags: plsql, abap, sap-basis

We are working with an SAP Oracle database and facing a challenge when attempting to read and decode the content of a specific field named `CLUSTD` in the `BALDAT` table. We have successfully read the field and converted its content from LRAW to hexadecimal. However, we are struggling to decode the hexadecimal content to its original format or understandable form.

Could anyone guide us on how to properly decode this content?

Comment: This column is zipped according to undocumented proprietary SAP zip algorithm. You can decode only by using ABAP. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901689/how-are-abap-data-clusters-stored-in-the-database.